# Слово "молочай"

Tags: этимология

Давно интересно было узнать, что означает название растения "молочай". "Моло-" — это, как я понимаю, от слова "молоко", потому что растение выделяет белый, похожий на молоко, сок. А вот при чем тут "чай"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Молоко - да (сок растения напоминает молоко, подобно, например, соку одуванчиков).
Чай  - нет. Это случайное созвучие.

Происходит от сущ. молоко (растение получило это название из-за своего горького сока, внешне напоминающего молоко), далее из праслав. формы *melko, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. млѣко (др.-греч. γάλα), др-русск. молоко, русск., укр. молоко, белор. малако, болг. мляко, хорв. mliko/mlijeko, словенск., польск., сербск. mleko, чешск. mléko, словацк. mlieko, кашубск. mlóu̯ko, в.-луж., н.-луж. mloko (слав.* melko восходит к праиндоевр. *melg-). Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

**Ч** - это скорее всего смягченное **К** из "млеко", а **ЯЙ** - некогда весьма продуктивный суффикс, который находим в существительных типа *обычай*, *случай*, рудиментарно собственных - Митяй, Федяй и проч. 
Как вариант **Ч** может быть другим древним суффиксом, это это менее вероятно.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, что "при чём".Видимо, ассоциация с "молочным чаем",млечный сок молочая использовался в лечении издавна, первоначально и в виде настоев, как все чаи.

Само слово ЧАЙ, первично ЧА , буквально означает «молодой листок» и стало употребляться для обозначения чая в IV-V веке – как раз тогда, когда чай стали изготавливать из этих самых молодых листков. До этого чай как только не называли: «доу», «цзя», «куту», «чжунь», «мин», «ту».
Молочай, как лечебное, и в то же время ядовитое растение был известен с древнейших времен. Целители всех времен были уверены в том, что млечный сок обладает мочегонным, слабительным, потогонным, противовоспалительным, рвотным, отвлекающим, обезболивающим и противоглистным действием.Врачи и целители всегда предупреждали об опасности внутреннего применения молочая в виде настоев и отваров из-за явного раздражающего действия на желудочно-кишечный тракт,но по виду это всё-таки был чай.

Comment: То есть слово это русско-китайское? А куда делось _к_ из "молока"?